# Same question multiple sites

Tags: discussion, questions

Since many applications of GIS are multi-disciplinary in nature, I was wondering whether it is correct to post the same question in multiple stackexchange sites.

For example, many times when dealing with coding for GIS applications I am faced with problems which are partly coding related and partly geography related. Will it be right to post the same question in both gis.stackexchange and stackoverflow site for a quick reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is thoughtful of you to ask, but the answer is a very clear NO: see [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) on the SO Meta site for why and for your options.